# Whether a feasible set is empty?

Tags: linear-programming

Given $a\in \mathbb{R}^N$ with at least one positive entry, and a positive definite $N\times N$ matrix $A$, I would like to prove the following set is non-empty:

$$S=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^N :  x\geq 0, Ax\geq a\}$$

Comment: Is the idea here that $S$ depends on a choice of vector $a$?

Comment: @hardmath Yes I guess and for any $a$ (with the given condition), the set is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite, $\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n\text{ (non-zero)},\mathbf{x}^t\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}>0$. Now following this, what can you say about our inequality $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\geq \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{a}$ given that at least one entry of $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is positive?